# Can you define an array formula across multiple columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a table of Stores (well, for this example anyway):

```
Store_ID Store_Name  ...
1        High Street
2        Low Street
...
```

I have another table of Employees:

```
Employee_ID Store_ID Is_Active
1           1        Y
2           1        Y
3           1        N
4           2        N
5           2        N
6           2        Y
```

I would like to count the number of active employees for a given store.

In other words, I want my output table to look like:

```
Store_ID Active_Employees
1        2
2        1
```

If I simply want to count the number of employees at a store, given that column A contains the Store_ID I can do so using an array formula:

```
{=SUM(IF($A2=Employees!$B$2:$B$1048576, 1, 0))}
```

However, when I attempt to take activity into account:

```
{=SUM(IF(AND($A2=Employees!$B$2:$B$1048576, Employees!$C$2:$C$1048576="Y"), 1, 0))}
```

then I get 0 for everything.

I'm guessing that using two separate array ranges is not stepping them along together, as I expected.

So essentially I have two questions:

- is it possible to move two arrays along in step using an array formula?
- if not, how can I achieve what I'm after?

EDIT: This appears to work correctly if I use nested IF statements rather than AND.  I am very confused...

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't need to be an array formula to do this. It can be done with a [`COUNTIFS`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countifs-function-HA010047494.aspx) formula.

For instance the below formula will count the number of instances from given range on the Employees sheet which meet the `Store_ID` from cell 'A2' **AND** equals 'Y' in column `C` of the Employees sheet.

```
=COUNTIFS(Employees!$B$2:$B$1048576,A2,Employees!$C$2:$C$1048576,"Y")
```